# No message field with Unauthorized Exceptions in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I have made a custom exception which should give the message to client when raised. However, that does not seem to be working whenever error code is 401 i.e. UNAUTHORIZED. I tried changing the status code to something else, and message showed up.

Note - I have already set the flag `server.error.include-message=always` in application.properties

**BadCredentialsException.java**

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class BadCredentialsException extends RuntimeException{
    // Runtime exception just needs this, I guess :/
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    public BadCredentialsException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
```

}

Here's how I have tried raising the exception.

```
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> loginUser(String username, String password){
    
    // validating username
    User user = myUserRepository.findByUsername(username).
    orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("No username: " + username + " found. Please enter a correct username!"));
    
    // validating password
    if(!new BCryptPasswordEncoder().matches(password, user.getPassword())){
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Incorrect Password. Please enter correct password to login!");
    }        

    return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
}
```

Note - message is correctly being displayed in the terminal though. Just not showing up on the client.

UPDATE 1 - I have made this particular endpoint to be accessible by everyone, using permitAll(). In postman, when I select select "no auth" and call this endpoint with expected exception, exception does not give the message unless, I give correct basic auth credentials (any role). I have absolutely no clue why this is happening.

UPDATE 2 - Adding SecurityConfiguration code.

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().
    authorizeRequests().        
    antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v2/user/login/**").permitAll().
    antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v2/user/", "/api/v2/user", "/api/v2/user/change-role/**").hasAuthority("ROOT").
    antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v2/user/", "/api/v2/user").hasAuthority("ROOT").
    antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/customers/", "/api/v1/customers").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "ROOT").
    antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/customers/", "/api/v1/customers").hasAnyAuthority("EMPLOYEE", "ADMIN", "ROOT").
    anyRequest().
    authenticated().
    and().
    httpBasic();
}
```

Comment: Spring Boot stopped exposing exception message in responses in newer versions. You need to either handle the response in `@RestControllerAdvice` or `throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "your message string")`

Comment: Thanks @SergVasylchak. I thought something like this might be the reason. How can one check if they have stopped doing something like this? Is it on their docs?

Comment: Did you config Spring security for your application or not?

Comment: @FaramarzAfzali Yes I did, I am adding an update to share the Config file code.

Comment: @Anant I posted an answer.

Comment: @SergVasylchak I tried using `throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "your message string")` but it shows identical behaviour to @ResponseStatus over BadCredentialsException class. Something is stopping responseBody to go to client when status code is 401/403. I read the docs but couldn't find anything that I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there are multiple ways to do that.
First, as **@SergVasylchak** said in the comments, you can use `ControllerAdvice`.
So the approach is like below:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

 @ExceptionHandler(BadCredentialsException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    private Message handleMessageAuth(BadCredentialsException e, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setTimestamp(getTimeStamp());
        message.setError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        message.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        message.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        message.setPath(String.valueOf(request.getRequestURI()));
        return message;
    }
}
```

`Message` is your custom pojo.

```java
public class Message {
    private String timestamp;
    private int status;
    private String error;
    private String message;
    private String path;
// getters & setters
}
```

---

Another solution is that implement `AuthenticationEntryPoint`.

What is AuthenticationEntryPoint?

> It is an interface implemented by ExceptionTranslationFilter,
> basically a filter which is the first point of entry for Spring
> Security. It is the entry point to check if a user is authenticated
> and logs the person in or throws exception (unauthorized). Usually, the
> class can be used like that in simple applications but when using
> Spring security in REST, JWT etc one will have to extend it to provide
> better Spring Security filter chain management.
> AuthenticationEntryPoint is used in Spring Web Security to configure
> an application to perform certain actions whenever an unauthenticated
> client tries to access private resources.

Look at [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html).

> AuthenticationEntryPoint is used to send an HTTP response that
> requests credentials from a client. Sometimes a client will
> proactively include credentials such as a username/password to request
> a resource. In these cases, Spring Security does not need to provide
> an HTTP response that requests credentials from the client since they
> are already included. In other cases, a client will make an
> unauthenticated request to a resource that they are not authorized to
> access. In this case, an implementation of AuthenticationEntryPoint is
> used to request credentials from the client. The
> AuthenticationEntryPoint implementation might perform a redirect to a
> log in page, respond with a WWW-Authenticate header, etc.

For example, if you have a JWT authentication the approach is like below.

```java
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
// if you want to return 401 status, this is enough.

// if you want to customize your response you can make it as below.
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getOutputStream().println("{ \"error\": \"" + authException.getMessage() + "\" }"); 
    }
}
```

Now it's time to config the AuthenticationEntryPoint in SecurityConfig.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().
   .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
   .and()
    authorizeRequests().        
    antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v2/user/login/**").permitAll().
    antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v2/user/", "/api/v2/user", "/api/v2/user/change-role/**").hasAuthority("ROOT").
    antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v2/user/", "/api/v2/user").hasAuthority("ROOT").
    antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/customers/", "/api/v1/customers").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "ROOT").
    antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/customers/", "/api/v1/customers").hasAnyAuthority("EMPLOYEE", "ADMIN", "ROOT").
    anyRequest().
    authenticated().
    and().
    httpBasic();
}
}
```